# Backtracking a balancing group in a greedy repetition may cause imbalance?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, backtracking, balancing-groups

As a generically brewed example for the purpose of this question, my intent is to match some number of `a`'s, then an equal number of `b`'s, plus one more `b`.

Examine the two patterns exhibited in this snippet ([also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/Neg2N)):

```
var r1 = new Regex(@"(?xn)
   (?<A> a)+   (?<B-A> b)+    (?(A)(?!))   b
");
var r2 = new Regex(@"(?xn)
   (?<A> a)+   (?<B-A> b)+?   (?(A)(?!))   b
");

Console.WriteLine(r1.Match("aaabbb"));
// aaabbb

Console.WriteLine(r2.Match("aaabbb"));
// aabbb
```

Note that there is a difference in the matches of the two patterns. `r1`, which uses a greedy repetition on the balancing group construct, matches 3 `a`'s and 3 `b`'s, which is *NOT* as intended. `r2`, which uses a reluctant repetition, gives me 2 `a`'s and 3 `b`'s, which *IS* as intended.

The only way I can explain this is that when `(?<B-A> b)+` backtracks to match one less `b`, it pops from the `B` stack but *DOES NOT* push back what was correspondingly popped from the `A` stack. Thus, even though one less `b` is now matched due to backtracking, the `A` stack remains empty. This is the only way I can explain how `r1` can match `aaabbb`.

Note that using reluctant `+?` in `r2` doesn't cause this problem. The way I see it, this is because unlike greedy repetition, a reluctant repetition doesn't have to "undo the damage" to the `A` stack, so-to-speak. By contrast, the greedy repetition causes as much "damage" as possible, but the backtracking fails to "leave things as they were" to the `A` stack.

Is this a correct analysis of what happened? And if so, is this behavior by design? Because what it basically looks like to me is that backtracking a balancing group in a greedy repetition may cause imbalance, and thus this could potentially be categorized as a bug (or at the very least a somewhat astonishing behavior that is inadequately documented).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your observations. I pasted your code directly into Visual Studio and it outputs `aabbb` both times, as expected.

Comment: Works for me as well. I am using version 4.0 of the .NET framework.

Comment: @Jens, @Timwi: do you know of any other online apps where I can paste my C# snippet and have it run against various versions of the .NET framework? Because obviously the one on ideone.com gives a different output.

Comment: RegExLib.com (http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx)

Comment: Nope, sorry. Ideone only tells that its using the 2.0 compiler, which means .NET 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5.

Comment: If you print [`Environment.Version` on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/KpTp6) you get 2.0.50727.1433 (runtime version). I cannot reproduce the bug targeting .Net 2.0, but I have version  2.0.50727.4206.

Comment: @Jens - It is unlikely they use the 2.0 compiler, it supports lambdas and `var`.

Comment: @Kobi: lambda and var were introduced somewhere in 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5, all of which are using the same compiler and clr(the 2.0 one) (see the wikipeia, e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#.NET_Framework_3.0)

Comment: "astonishing behavior" is that regular expressions are being used for what is clearly a non-regular context-free language :-)

Comment: Update: With Microsoft opening much of the .Net source code, Mono will be using Microsoft's implementation for `System.Text.RegularExpressions`, so I'm expecting most of these Mono-specific bugs to go away: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/4.0.0/ .

Answer (score 2):

This is a [bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3866) in Mono.

The reason why people are getting .NET-like `Environment.Version` on IdeOne is Mono requirement of backward compatibility with .NET, including compatibility with applications that take decisions based on the framework version.